# How do I implement chess with backbone.js with a RESTful api?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, websocket, chess

When one player makes a move that is sent to the server. And that move is pushed by the server to the second player. As far as I know, the server pushing the move to the second player goes against being a RESTful api.

From what little I know about backbone.js it is meant really for RESTful setups. Is there a way to use backbone.js with websockets to allow the server to push data down to the clients at any time?

Is there even an idiomatic way of implementing chess with backbone.js and websockets? And if not then what would be the correct way to implement chess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it.  Instead of fetching your collection/model, you will just `set` or `update`/`reset` the json data from the websocket into the proper model or collection.

Somewhat pseudo-code example:

```
var board = new Backbone.Collection(); // this would probably be your own extended Collection instead.

function boardChange(jsonFromServer){
   // Take the json array from server,
   // and update the collection with it.
   // This would trigger 'change' events in each model in the collection (if changed).
   board.update(jsonFromServer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a chess app doesn't really require a `Backbone` architecture. As long as your server supports `Asynchronous API`, `WebSockets`, or even `long-polling` (anything real-time), it's possible. There's tons of `API`s out there on the web already that does this (ie [FireBase](https://www.firebase.com/)) as well as frameworks (ie, [Meteor](http://meteor.com/)) comes into mind.

Also check out [Socket IO](http://socket.io/) if you're using [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) for your server-side. There's tons of open source projects on GitHub that takes advantage of some of these web technologies already, Backbone in particular. [Backbone with Socket IO](https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io). [Backbone.ioBind](http://alogicalparadox.com/backbone.iobind/) also looks like a promising project with code samples that you can look at.

To make it work with `Backbone`, the data API just needs to notify any client-side listeners that an update has been made on the server which in turn triggers a `change` event on your Backbone `Model`.

You can even set a timer that performs a request to the server every `n` amount of time just to test out your code prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the Backbone.sync method to use websockets. The de-facto To-Do example (http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) does this to use localstorage instead of a RESTful datastore, and you could do the same for web sockets. In fact if you look around Github/Google you may be able to find someone who's already done it.